# Finding out the correct CRC polynomial

Tags: byte, crc16

I am using simpleBGC gimbal controller from Basecam electronics. The controller has a serial API for communication which requires the calculation of crc16 checksum for the commands sent to the controller(https://www.basecamelectronics.com/file/SimpleBGC_2_6_Serial_Protocol_Specification.pdf) (page 3)

I want to send the reset command to the controller which has the following format:

Header: {start char: '$', command id: '114', payload size: '3', header checksum : '117'}

Payload: {3,0,0} (3 bytes corresponding to reset options and time to reset)

crc16 checksum : ? (using polynomial 0x8005 calculated for all bytes **except start char**)

The hex representation of my command is: 0x24720375030000 and I need to find crc16 checksum for 0x720375030000. I used different crc calculators but the controller is not responding to the command and I assume that crc checksum is not correct.
To find correct crc16 checksum I sent every possible combination of crc16 checksum and found out that the controller responds when checksum is '7b25'.
so the correct command in hex is : "24 720375030000 7b25".
But this checksum 7b25 does not correspond to the polynomial 0x8005.
How can I find the correct polynomial or crc16 calculation function?

Comment: Link for Basecam electronics serial API manual:
https://www.basecamelectronics.com/serialapi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the code in the appendix of the document you linked? It works fine, and produces `0x257b` for the CRC of your example data. That is then written in the stream in little-endian order, giving the `7b 25` you are expecting.

Here is a simpler and faster C implementation than what is in the appendix:

```
#include <stddef.h>

// Return a with the low 16 bits reversed and any bits above that zeroed.
static unsigned rev16(unsigned a) {
    a = (a & 0xff00) >> 8 | (a & 0x00ff) << 8;
    a = (a & 0xf0f0) >> 4 | (a & 0x0f0f) << 4;
    a = (a & 0xcccc) >> 2 | (a & 0x3333) << 2;
    a = (a & 0xaaaa) >> 1 | (a & 0x5555) << 1;
    return a;
}

// Implement the CRC specified in the BASECAM SimpleBGC32 2.6x serial protocol
// specification. Return crc updated with the length bytes at message. If
// message is NULL, then return the initial CRC value. This CRC is like
// CRC-16/ARC, but with the bits reversed.
//
// This is a simple bit-wise implementation. Byte-wise and word-wise algorithms
// using tables exist for higher speed if needed. Also this implementation
// chooses to reverse the CRC bits as opposed to the data bits, as done in the
// specficiation appendix. The CRC only needs to be reversed once at the start
// and once at the end, whereas the alternative is reversing every data byte of
// the message. Reversing the CRC twice is faster for messages with length
// greater than two bytes.
unsigned crc16_simplebgc(unsigned crc, void const *message, size_t length) {
    if (message == NULL)
        return 0;
    unsigned char const *data = message;
    crc = rev16(crc);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return rev16(crc);
}

#include <stdio.h>

// Example usage of crc_simplebgc(). A CRC can be computed all at once, or with
// portions of the data at a time.
int main(void) {
    unsigned crc = crc16_simplebgc(0, NULL, 0);         // set initial CRC
    crc = crc16_simplebgc(crc, "\x72\x03\x75", 3);      // first three bytes
    crc = crc16_simplebgc(crc, "\x03\x00\x00", 3);      // remaining bytes
    printf("%04x\n", crc);                              // prints 257b
    return 0;
}
```